# Is it possible to use Facebook API to search for videos from Facebook Pages around a specific location?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can I use the Facebook API to find all Facebook Pages or Places around a specific geographic location that have posted public videos recently?

I don't believe there is a way to do it directly, but could I do it by first finding place id's or page id's, and then using those place ids to see if those pages have posted a video recently?

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically you could start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places - although the docs seem currently broken, quite a few pages below that return a 404.

Comment: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/2020-02-03-endpoint-deprecations#places says, `GET /{place-information-id}` was deprecated - so I am not sure right now, if maybe they are fading that feature out again already?)

Comment: Is there anything that returns whether or not there is a video posted?  Thank you with regard to the 404 errors, I thought that was me!

Comment: Making a request to `/page-id/videos` would get you a list of videos published by that page. But for public pages you have no admin access to, you would need to submit your app for review of the Page Public Content Access feature.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how long it would take FB to approve that?